# Getting top most called names in a dataset based on certain columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, count

I was wondering if someone could help me with a small query..
I currently have a massive dataset with a large amount of rows and I wanted to create a smaller dataframe that only pulls 2 columns from the larger one and how many times each name occurred in that chapter in this instance 'Occurrence'

The below code is what I am using

```
 df1 = (Dec16.groupby(["BNF Chapter", "Name"]).size().reset_index(name="Occurrence"))
df1
```

It plots this

```
BNF Chapter       Name                                       Occurrence 
1                 Aluminium hydroxide                           2
1                 Aluminium hydroxide + Magnesium trisilicate   2
1                 Alverine                                      702
.......
21              Polihexanide                                     2
21              Potassium hydroxide                              32
21              Sesame oil                                       22
21              Sodium chloride                                  222
```

What I would like to get is the top 10 most occurred names for a certain chapter  as the dataset is so large.

For example a dataframe that only pulls 
The top 10 most common names in chapter 1

How would I go about doing this?

Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Let's do a little example with a random variable generator.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# we create random integers in 3 columns
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,(1000,3)), columns=["A","B","C"])
# we want to count the repetitions of C given A and B
result = df.groupby(["A","B"]).count()
# the result will print something like this, counting the repetitions of A and B
#       C
# A B    
# 0 0  11
#   1  10
#   2   5
#   3  12
#   4   9
#   5  12
#   6   7
#   7   8
```